# Does Otiluke's Resilient Sphere on creature that swallowed another prevent escaping the swallow?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

Does Otiluke's Resilient Sphere prevent an engulfed/swallowed creature from escaping? I can think of two examples to show what I mean:

1. A creature is swallowed by a Gelatinous Cube, then ORS is cast on the Cube. Does that mean the swallowed creature is irrevocably considered engulfed until ORS is dispelled?
2. A creature is swallowed by a Giant Toad and ORS is cast on the Giant Toad, then the Giant Toad is killed by the creature it had swallowed. Would ORS prevent that creature from escaping, and cause it to continue taking acid damage since it can't escape?

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, it's just that I have lead on questions stemming from early ones. I'll tidy it up and only keep 1 question

Comment: Lead-on questions are okay, but it's rare that a lead-on question is the *same* question, so they typically have to be posted separately to follow the one-post-one-question rule. (A rule of thumb I sometimes find useful is to see if a descriptive title can be written about the whole post, without having to cover two topics in the title.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Yes, they are engulfed until dispelled

ORS says:

> Nothing, not physical Objects, energy, or other spell effects, can pass through the barrier, in or out, though a creature in the Sphere can breathe there.

and a Gelatinous Cube's engulf says:

> An engulfed creature can try to escape by taking an action to make a DC 12 Strength check. On a success, the creature escapes and enters a space of its choice within 5 feet of the cube.

So since a creature cannot leave ORS and ORS is around the Gelatinous Cube, the engulfed creature cannot get 5 feet away from the Gelatinous Cube and thus cannot dis-engulf themselves from it

## 2. Yes they can escape and prevent further damage

> If the toad dies, a swallowed creature is no longer Restrained by it and can escape from the corpse using 5 feet of Movement, exiting prone.

When the giant toad dies the character is no longer restrained. By spending 5 feet of movement the character can free itself from the giant toad corpse and thus not continue taking damage. ORS does not prevent this because the 5 feet of movement does but actually move you five feet (and thus would not cause you to hit the ORS barrier), it is just a cost to escape the stomach if the giant toad. This is similar to the way that spending movement to stand up from prone does not move you anywhere but just let's you stand up.

Presumably, after the giant toad's death and having spent 5 ft of moment to escape the swallow you will be prone in the same square as the giant toad corpse, but you will not be taking acid damage. However ORS will still be surrounding the giant toad corpse (ORS can affect objects or creatures so it shouldn't vanish).

Comment: What about escaping from a Giant Toad's swallow? Let's say the PC it swallows kills the Giant Toad that's inside an ORS and tries to escape. Does the PC still take damage because he or she can't actually leave the sphere?

Comment: @BaconHero: Generally, asking additional questions should constitute a new post or an edit to your current one. This one is pretty easy though. When a creature dies RAW, their abilities stop working. So no damage. A DM might rule differently based on the situation of course. For example being in a creature with an acidic ability. Death would not necessarily logically immediately negate that kind of thing so I might rule that the character takes some damage.

Comment: @BaconHero: Actually you should consider making that an new question after checking to see if something similar has been asked before. It wouldn't have to involve ORS at all.

Comment: The question has been significantly edited. You might want to revise this answer now.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose If it's the difference between the question staying closed and getting reopened, yes. (And for some other reasons, but that's the one relevant here.) Generally, it's considered that answering a two-question question naturally carries the risk that the question may soon change and the answer will need revising to make sense.

Comment: There are a few questions about changed questions, from different angles, on the Meta site that might be interesting to dig through. Searching for [`change question` turns them up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=change+question) (though there are unrelated ones in the results that you have to skip over).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> An engulfed creature can try to escape by taking an action to make a
>   DC 12 Strength check. On a success, the creature escapes and enters a
>   space of its choice within 5 feet of the cube.

From the diagram we can see that there is space in at least 8/12 of the adjacent spaces. Yes they can't get entirely into the next square, but a character doesn't take up the entire square.

The question then becomes how viscous (If that is the right word) the Gelatinous Cube is, because staying out might be harder or easier. I would rule that since heavy objects float inside then it takes a reasonable force to actually get engulfed and the person won't automatically fall back in.

Since the person is pre-occupied with staying in the safe space I would give then disadvantage on everything or similar; possibly an athletics check to not fall in due to the curved nature of the floor they are standing on but that would be complete house-rule territory.

The Giant Toad is easier, once you kill it you climb out and stand on the corpse, so you are safe from the stomach acid.

Comment: Hmm I didn't consider a creature being able to enter and stay in a half square, but since this is a sphere, that square is also not going to be on the ground but sloped steeply towards the GC.